# Python OpenCV VideoCapture won't show webcam images

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, video-capture

I'm working with Python OpenCV and want to capture webcam images to a frame, but the output was always showing this instead of my webcam images.

[image: Output]

The script is as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Does anyone know the problem? Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any warning messages?

Comment: @jeru-luke: no warning messages from Python, but the window frame couldn't show any captured images.

Comment: windows or ubuntu?

Comment: @jeru-luke: Windows

Comment: Firstly check if your camera is compatible on [THIS LINK](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS)

Comment: Check [THIS LINK](https://web.archive.org/web/20120815172655/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS/) is the earlier mentioned link does not work

Comment: @JustinusHermawan This is because Camera is not connected on your IP application.

Answer (score -1):

Add a line to write a frame image to a file, JPG or PNG. It works in my PC.

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cv2.imwrite('capframe.jpg',frame)
    break
```

Did you verify if the image capture of your webcam works by its or other software?